# Installing the Homewerks Bath fan Bluetooth speaker and LED Light

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

The connection to the exhaust fan housing unit contains 2 green ground connections a white and a black fan connection as well as a black and a white light kit connection. My existing wiring contains the ground (green) hot (black) and neutral (white) wires. How do I connect my existing wiring to the exhaust housing connections. [image]

Comment: Do you know if the incoming black wire into the box is an always-hot or a switched-hot?

Comment: Not sure i understand your question… do you mean if when it was originally installed was the black wire “hot” if so yes. It has never been changed or tampered with until now. The house is a new construction build if that helps as well

Comment: follow the fan installation instructions

Answer (score 1):

Your question need a bit more information to answer correctly.  Simply, is there a switch on the wall that is used to turn the fan on?  If so determine if that switch provides the power to the black wire in your ceiling. If that is confirmed, you can attach the 2 blacks from the fan and the black in the ceiling together, all 3 white wires go together as do all 3 green and bare copper grounds.

This will result in the fan and the light both coming on when activated by the wall switch.

If you desire some other working combination, the wiring in the house must be changed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful 